# Do I need a UK visa for my Peruvian baby if I am British?

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel, uk-citizens, peruvian-citizens

I am British, living in Peru. My 4 month old baby so far only has a Peruvian passport. We travel in 6 weeks so no time to apply for a British passport for him. Do I need to apply for a visa for him for the UK and we are also travelling to Vienna so another one for Austria?

Comment: I think the fast track passport is just if you are in the UK, it's more complicated from Peru. I can ask the Embassy here but since it's the weekend, I was hoping for a quicker answer.

Comment: @pnuts Overseas passport applications get posted to the UK, where it takes [six weeks _from the time it arrives in the UK_ to process](https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports/y/peru/applying/child/peru). The poster had plenty of time to do this, but for whatever reason chose not to. Now there is not enough time.

Comment: Missing info: if you are listed on the child's birth certificate? has the child been registered? if you are travelling with the child's bio mother? the length of your travel?  why the child has not been registered? Marking as 'unclear', please edit.

Comment: @GayotFow, if that child **is** an UK citizen, that would have to be disclosed on the visa application and the child would be unable to get an UK visa for that reason, right?

Comment: @o.m. while it's a given that the child needs to be properly documented, the big hot button will be about abduction, trafficking, surrogacy, and those types of things.  And how long the parents want to be detained until those issues are cleared up to the IO's satisfaction.

Comment: Are you the childs biological mother (with a user name of Betty and the use of 'My child' I assume you are. If so, is the father also UK citizen or does he needs/has visa for the UK.

Comment: @phoog, I wrote "british" and corrected that before I posted ...

Comment: "another one for Austria": Nationals of Peru do not require a visa to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog, I edited back and forth and made a mistake. Is that really worth *two* comments on Travel SE? On English SE I'd understand it.

Comment: @o.m. no it isn't.  After your "british" response I thought perhaps that you had misunderstood my reason for posting the comment.  I will delete them.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have now added some clarification to my question